# ERROR 1045 (28000) on mysql-server installation

Tags: password, sudo, mysql

I am new to Ubuntu trying to install MySQL.

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql`

then to create database directory structure

`sudo mysql_install_db`

Then to secure I use

`sudo mysql_secure_installation`

and then it ask me to

`Enter current password for root`

I am logged as root by using `sudo su` but when I try entering the password it give me

```
error:Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' 
(using password: YES)
```

By typing y for yes also it is giving the same error.
please help me.

Comment: @Parto when I am running mysql -u root it again give error, ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: I hope you are not still using a root terminal - that is as `sudo su`? If so, type `exit` then follow the steps in the linked question on how to reset your password. You seem to have forgotten your MySQL password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reset your mysqld password just follow these instructions :

Stop the mysql demon process using this command :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Start the mysqld demon process using the --skip-grant-tables option with this command

```
 sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Because you are not checking user privs at this point, it's safest to disable networking. In Dapper, /usr/bin/mysqld... did not work. However, mysqld --skip-grant-tables did.

start the mysql client process using this command

```
mysql -u root
```

from the mysql prompt execute this command to be able to change any password

```
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then reset/update your password

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

If you have a mysql root account that can connect from everywhere, you should also do:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

Alternate Method:

```
   USE mysql
   UPDATE user SET Password = PASSWORD('newpwd')
   WHERE Host = 'localhost' AND User = 'root';
```

once have received a message indicating a successful query (one or more rows affected), flush privileges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then stop the mysqld process and relaunch it with the classical way:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

There is another way using "Purge" given in link

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset)

Comment: while setting up password it is giving an error ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: Just Try to `exit` from mysql and then restart the service with `service mysqld restart` if `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` doesn't works then try `flush-privileges;`